# How to find $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1)+\sin(\frac{1}{2})+\dots+\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(1)+\sin(\frac{1}{2})+\dots+\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}
> $$

I tried applying Cesaro Stolz and found its $(\sin 1/(n+1))/\ln(n+1)/n$ where $\ln$ is $\log_e$ and it would be $1$ and so the limit is $0$, but in my book the answer is $2$. Am I doing something wrong or can't Cesaro be applied here?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Im on phone I cant see what it will type

Comment: I think you mean $\frac {sin 1+ sin \frac {1}{2}+\cdots+ sin \frac {1}{n}}{ln n}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(1)+\sin(\frac{1}{2})+\dots+\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{1}{k})}{\ln(n)}$$

Applying Stolz-Cesàro yields

$$\ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sin(\frac{1}{k})-\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(\frac{1}{k})}{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}= \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n+1})}{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}=$$
$$\ =\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n+1})}{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}\sim \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$$

Where I used the fact that for $\ x\to 0$, $\sin(x)\sim x$, and $\ln(1+x)\sim x$

Comment: how do you make that aproximation?

Comment: Edited. You can see here also http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_eduen/mat/infiequi.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin1+\sin\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\ln n}
$$
you can indeed try and apply [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) with
$$
a_n=\sin1+\sin\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\sin\frac{1}{n}
\qquad
b_n=\ln n
$$
This leads to computing
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n+1}}{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}
$$
This limit will exist if the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin x}{\ln\frac{1}{x}-\ln(\frac{1}{x}-1)}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{\sin x}{\ln(1-x)}
$$
exists and they'll be equal.

Comment: why is the last limit equal with$$\lim_{x\to0^+}-\frac{\sin x}{\ln(1-x)}
$$

Comment: @Lola $\ln(\frac{1}{x}-1)=\ln\frac{1-x}{x}=\ln(1-x)+\ln\frac{1}{x}$